# Problem installing Knowledge base module

Tags: installation

I installed Drupal using the Bitnami stack.
I'm trying to install the knowledge base module from https://www.drupal.org/project/kb .  I have installed and enabled the modules upon which it is dependent but when I try to enable the knowledge base module itself I get the error

Unable to install KnowledgeBase due to unmet dependencies: core.entity_form_display.node.kb_content.default (field.field.node.kb_content.body)

Obviously I am still missing a dependency and it's telling me what it is but what is but how do I fulfill the requirement?

Further, I can see the core.entity_form_display.node.kb_content.default yml file in C:\Bitnami\drupal-8.7.2-1\apps\drupal\htdocs\modules\kb\config\install when I use file explorer.

Is the yml file in the wrong place?  Or do I need to do something with it so the knowledgebase install knows about it?

Can someone tell me what I need to do?  Please excuse if it's obvious I am a newbie to Drupal.

Thanks for any help, Roscoe

Answer (score 0):

The install yml is not in the wrong place.  This is a new module with 1 install currently in beta state so you might face a few problems with it if not all bugs are not ironed out but perhaps this is not the case.

The error message is not that helpful I must admit. If you want to see what dependencies you are missing you go into the .info.yml file and can also [be seen online here](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/kb/blob/8.x-1.x/kb.info.yml) and here is the relevant section

```
...
dependencies:
  - drupal:field
  - drupal:file
  - drupal:text
  - drupal:node
  - drupal:group
  - drupal:gnode
  - drupal:views
  - drupal:views_jump_menu
  - drupal:eva
```

for field, file, text, node, views are part of core (nothing to do)

but you have to download 
https://www.drupal.org/project/group (for group and gnode)
https://www.drupal.org/project/views_jump_menu 
https://www.drupal.org/project/eva

before you are able to install this module

I suggest that you start looking into installing things using composer that takes care of the dependencies for you so if you did

```
composer require drupal/kb
```

all the dependencies would also be installed for you

More info about composer based drupal installations can be found [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/install) and [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-composer-to-install-drupal-and-manage-dependencies) and perhaps other places but those are good starting points

Comment: Hi GiorgosK thanks for the quick reply.  Taking another look at he kb Drupal site at https://www.drupal.org/project/kb   I see  that my issue is an open bug previously reported on a composer download at https://www.drupal.org/project/kb/issues/3051986 .  I think I will look for another more mature solution for a knowledge base.  Perhaps a combination of wikki with QandA with a bit of document storage would work.  I was really trying to find a canned solution though if you have any recommendations.  I will check the bug reports in future.  Thanks for the lesson I'm a newbie, Cheers, Roscoe